# how execute shell scripts from app on Android Q

Tags: android, android-10.0

Android 10 has modified how apps will access to storage files.

Now storage files needs to be accessed using [content providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider#java).

In my app I need to execute files in a folder via "`sh`" command.
When a user selects the folder that contains the files, in Android 10 the folder pathname is in the form:

> content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/xxxx-xxxx:a/b

(`a/b` is the pathname inside `/storage/xxxx-xxxx`)
and I can get the files in the folder using a cursor.
But when I try to execute the files via "

> sh /storage/xxxx-xxxx/a/b/f.sh

" I receive a permission denied error.

Is there a way to get a pathname that can be accessible from a `shell` in Android 10?

Comment: you need to copy the file in your private folder returned from getFilesDir() for example and then use the command there